# How to install vlc on centos7 from terminal?

Tags: linux, centos, vlc, fedora-21

I want to install vlc on centos7. I following some steps mentioned on internet. When I try to run 
1.**yum update** then 
2.**yum install vlc**, it is giving following error.
I am getting something following suggestion
**You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem

    You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest**

```
    Error: Package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
           Requires: libnotify.so.1()(64bit)
           Available: libnotify-0.5.0-1.el6.x86_64 (tejas-barot-vlc)
               libnotify.so.1()(64bit)
           Installed: libnotify-0.7.5-7.el7.x86_64 (@base/$releasever)
              ~libnotify.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.26()(64bit)
           Available: gnutls-2.8.5-14.el6_5.x86_64 (tejas-barot-vlc)
               libgnutls.so.26()(64bit)
           Installed: gnutls-3.3.8-12.el7.x86_64 (@base)
              ~libgnutls.so.28()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.26(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit)
           Available: gnutls-2.8.5-14.el6_5.x86_64 (tejas-barot-vlc)
               libgnutls.so.26(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit)
           Installed: gnutls-3.3.8-12.el7.x86_64 (@base)
              ~libgnutls.so.28(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit)
              ~libgnutls.so.28(GNUTLS_2_10)(64bit)
              ~libgnutls.so.28(GNUTLS_2_12)(64bit)
              ~libgnutls.so.28(GNUTLS_2_8)(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
           Requires: libudev.so.0()(64bit)
           Available: libudev-147-2.57.el6.x86_64 (tejas-barot-vlc)
               libudev.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
           Requires: libproxy.so.0()(64bit)
           Available: libproxy-0.3.0-10.el6.x86_64 (tejas-barot-vlc)
               libproxy.so.0()(64bit)
           Installed: libproxy-0.4.11-6.el7.x86_64 (@base/$releasever)
              ~libproxy.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
           Requires: libmtp.so.8()(64bit)
           Available: libmtp-0.3.7-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
               libmtp.so.8()(64bit)
           Available: libmtp-1.0.1-2.el6.x86_64 (tejas-barot-vlc)
               libmtp.so.8()(64bit)
           Installed: libmtp-1.1.6-3.el7.x86_64 (@base/$releasever)
              ~libmtp.so.9()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I just **run yum repolist**

```
repo id               repo name                                           status
adobe-linux-x86_64    Adobe Systems Incorporated                               2
atrpms/7/x86_64       Fedora Core 7 - x86_64 - ATrpms                        827
base/7/x86_64         CentOS-7 - Base                                      8,652
epel/x86_64           Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64       7,602
extras/7/x86_64       CentOS-7 - Extras                                       84
google-chrome         google-chrome                                            3
linuxtech-release     LinuxTECH.NET el6 main repo                          1,161
nodesource/x86_64     Node.js Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64        29
openstack-juno        OpenStack Juno Repository                              953
rpmforge              RHEL 7 - RPMforge.net - dag                         11,403
tejas-barot-vlc       CentOS Repository for VLC Installation               6,518
updates/7/x86_64      CentOS-7 - Updates                                     300
repolist: 37,534
```

**We can see that EPEL list is enabled.** 
I followed from this link 
http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-enable-epel-repository-for-rhel-centos-6-5/

I ju

Answer (score 1):

Install or enable epel repository then you will be able to install vlc.

Comment: You can follow this http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-enable-epel-repository-for-rhel-centos-6-5/ this is surely a mirror list issue.

Comment: sorry  It is not working, I try what you suggested I am getting same error      and suggestion                                                                                                               "You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
    You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest"

Comment: I am getting same error, I also check the yum repolist, It is showing me that EPEL is enabled..

Comment: Run this command package-cleanup --problem it will list missing dependencies... install them hopefully it will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to install any software on Centos. We will be using YUM to install vlc. Before installing it you should check the version of Centos you are using by below command.

> cat /etc/centos-release

Now according to version of centos follow the instructions:-

**For Centos 7**

Step 1: Install  EPEL

> yum install epel-release

If you face any difficulty to install EPEL then follow the [link](http://www.unixmen.com/install-epel-repository-centos-rhel-7/).

> rpm -Uvh http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-1.el7.nux.noarch.rpm

**For Centos 6**

Step 1: Run below commands

> rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
>
> rpm -Uvh
> http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el6/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-2.el6.nux.noarch.rpm

Step 2: Update Yum

> yum update

Step 3: Install VLC

> yum install vlc

Step 4: Open VLC

> vlc -v

Congratulations!!! You have VLC installed.